# TypeScript cannot find globally referenced interface extension for SignalR

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, asp.net-core-mvc

I setup a .NET Core project using Angular 2, TypeScript, and SignalR. I have created and am using DefinitelyTyped's jQuery and SignalR typings.

Several articles (like this [one](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/08/08/signalr-typed.html)) have suggested I add some strong typing to my SignalR hub via interfaces that declare what is available on the hub server and client.

After a lot of adjustment I finally got the IDE happy: it detects the interfaces and extension without a fuss. However, whenever I go to build, TypeScript complains that it cannot find the name 'IRoomHub' (my hub interface name).

Here is the declaration for my interfaces, it is kept in a hubs.d.ts file in the signalr folder for my typings (globally installed):

```
interface SignalR {
    roomHub: IRoomHub;
}

interface IRoomHub {
    client: IRoomHubClient;
    server: IRoomHubServer;
}

interface IRoomHubClient {
    initiateTimer: (startMinutes: number) => void;
}

interface IRoomHubServer {
    initiateTimer(roomId: number, startMinutes: number): Promise<void>;
}
```

My usage is in my scripts folder:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RoomService } from './room.service';
import { Room } from './room';

@Component({
    selector: 'rooms',
    template: `...`,
    providers: [RoomService]
})
export class AdministrationPage implements OnInit { 

    roomHub: IRoomHub;

    constructor(private roomService: RoomService) { }

    rooms: Room[];

    initialize(room: Room) {
        this.roomHub.server.initiateTimer(room.id, room.startMinutes);
    }

    getRooms(): void {
        this.roomService.getRooms().then(rooms => this.rooms = rooms);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getRooms();
        this.roomHub = $.connection.roomHub;
    }
}
```

my tsConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/scripts/app",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

and my typings index.d.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/signalr/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/signalr/hubs.d.ts" />
```

I've tried changing from interface to export interface, surrounding it in a declare namespace and a declare module, but the compiler always has a problem finding it in one way or another. Additionally, it cannot find `$` either. my code is all available [here](https://github.com/Alphablackwolf/PuzzleTheory.RoomMonitor) in case I don't have enough information in my code examples.

Comment: I don't see a reference to hubs.d.ts anywhere, but I could have missed something.

Comment: sorry, most recently I took it out to test things, it was in my typings index. I'lm editing the post to include that.

Comment: I'm struggling with this too. But with ionic 2. Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have **jquery** in your **typings.json** file.

> "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery",

execute:
*typings install*

Hope it helps.